# Send data from android to website button

Tags: android, button, post, get, send

I have a Android app. I want to send a data to my website button.
something Like this :- http://mywebsite.com/gettoken="8937623847329823904"
Now the problem is that i don't know how to receive data from a url.

Here is my current website file :-

```
   if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['post']!='')
{

    $post=$_POST['post'];
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users order by id desc limit 75");
     $i=1;
     $token=array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

        $token[$i]=$row['token'];
        $url[$i] = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $post . "/likes?method=POST&access_token=" . $token[$i];
         $i++;


    }
     mysql_close($link);
    curlMultiRequest($url, $options = array());
   //  print_r($results);


}
function curlMultiRequest($urls, $options = array()) {
    $ch = array();
    $results = array();
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach($urls as $key => $val) {
        $ch[$key] = curl_init();
        if ($options) {
            curl_setopt_array($ch[$key], $options);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $val);
        curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$key]);
    }
    $running = null;
    do {
       usleep(100000);
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);

    }while ($running > 0);
    // Get content and remove handles.
    foreach ($ch as $key => $val) {
     //   $results[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent($val);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $val);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
   // return $results;
}
?>



<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="javascript: document.getElementById('show').style.display='block';">
    <input type="text" name="post"><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```